# How to copy folder contains excel files to another folder in Datalake to different container

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to copy one folder from one container to another container.
Source file format is excel and destination also will be same.

Just wanted to copy folder that contains excel file from one container to another.

Unable to do this as not getting sink data set as excel and it’s showing not supported in ADF. It’s just one time activity.

Answer (score 0):

> Unable to do this as not getting sink data set as excel and it’s showing not supported in ADF.

Yes, Currently, excel as sink is not supported in ADF. As you are just copying the folder, you can use [`Binary dataset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-binary) to copy the excel files.

Take two binary datasets for the source and target respectively.

This is a sample source folder containing excel files.

[image]

Create source binary dataset for the above and give the file path till the source container `excelcontainer`.

Use this for the copy activity source and use wild card file path(`<foldername*>` and `*.xlsx`) like below to copy the required folder.

[image]

Create the target binary dataset with the file path till the required target location like below.

[image]

Give this dataset as copy activity sink and Debug the pipeline. The required folder will be copied like below after the pipeline run.

[image]

Comment: @adf-learner if this answers your question then please consider "accepting" it by clicking the accept button next to it.